# Insert an image into a tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a tinymce text box on my html page. Under this text box I have a table with my file system in which I can navigate to locate my images. I would like to be able to click on an image in this table and have it inserted in the timymce text box. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've used the command

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" src="' + sr + '"/>');
```

to insert the image in tinyMCE after extracting the URL from the image's `src`.

Note that you need to pass the CSS style of the image to tinyMCE in the command.

EDIT: for Tiny MCE 4.x, the insert image code can be simplified to: `tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<img alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" src="' + sr + '"/>');`

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/Jyj7D/).

Comment: For Tiny MCE 4.x, the insert image code can be simplified to: `tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<img alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" src="' + sr + '"/>');`

Comment: I updated my old fiddle, the issue was that the library had been moved to a new URL. Now the fiddle supports the new version of TinyMCE library.

Answer (score 6):

The fiddle from user2314737 is broken. So I combine with Fei Hap Lee's solution to have working one.

```
        tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<img alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" src="' + sr + '"/>');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phuyem/gfk6n5ko/48/)