# tinymce-react Insert an image into a tinymce editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21854798/4239538) stackoverflow question, where we want to implement a custom image library and programatically add image to tinymice. The only difference is that we are using [tinymce-react plugin](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react) instead of installing tinymice in jquery.
My current tinymice configuration

```
<TinyMCE apiKey={"myKeyHere"}
            config={{
                height: 500,
                plugins: 'image table link',
                selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
                menubar: "insert",
                default_link_target: "_blank",
            }}
            content={this.props.value}
            onContentChanged={(event) => {
                {/*console.log(event)*/
                }
                this.props.onChange(event)
            }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be much simpler than I thought. I could just do

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
            tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<img alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="50" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTi7TskMwhabA1y8S5uSKON0ES5t6ehm9nUZO_5qjDFUUU52Y22qA"/>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

On the top of my page and it worked.

The only catch I saw was, it will insert the image ,even if no tinymice editor is active. But this can be worked around if we show the gallery only from tinymice editor.